# How to make Windows 10 BSOD show more details like older versions of Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, debug

I would like to know if there's any way to make Windows 10 show more details when crashing like Windows 7 did. In Windows 10, the Blue Screen of Death:

[image]

hides the parameters of the kernel panic:

[image]

The MSDN article [Blue Screen Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538869(v=vs.85).aspx) explains how to attach a debugger in the section titled "Reading Bug Check Information from the Debugger".

### Motivation

I have a BSOD issue right now ([Microsoft Support forums post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/memory-managementpage-fault-in-nonpaged-area-bsod/4a8b4d2c-6437-4d27-9d48-95b3a91e68a9)). If you can help with it it would be great.

We do need the actual log files (called `.dmp` files) as they contain the only record of the sequence of events leading up to the crash, what drivers were loaded, what was responsible, etc.

### Answered own question from Microsoft

Thanks for the help I just had to reinstall my windows using the UEFI method. It seems my BIOS firmware has buggy legacy support - I think.  When I'm using UEFI method to boot into a new version of Ubuntu there are no kernal panics. Everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to BSOD errors or general crash information like dump files?

Comment: Specifically BSOD way to debug error at the point it occurs

Comment: Please don't link to problem descriptions that are off-site. Include the information **in your question** using the [edit] link.

Comment: Be sure you are running the current version of your audio drivers, your current BSOD, is caused by  IntcDAud.sys which is an Intel driver.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"I would like to know if there's any way to make Windows 10 show more details when crashing like windows 7 did"

Yes you can.

Navigate to this registry entry

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl

Create a new DWORD value named **DisplayParameters** and set to 1

Restart and next time is BSOD's it will show you the old bluescreen with error message.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer does provide a way to get a more verbose blue screen message. However, post-event (as you may miss the screen showing up), it still outputs dump files in the same way that older versions of Windows did with more information. You can read these dumps using [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) Debugging Tools for Windows, or [NirSoft BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) - an easier to use alternative that has the ability to mock up a blue screen like the one you're referring to.

Blue screen dumps are, by default, saved in `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP` for Complete Memory Dumps, or in `%SystemRoot%\Minidump` as Minidumps. You can change this setting by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> `System` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Startup and Recovery Settings`. The dropdown box at the bottom states what you're currently using. I would recommend `Minidumps` as this way you can keep several of them without them overwriting each other.

Comment: Thankyou can you answer the next question?

Comment: @PasinduPerera Use BlueScreenView to find out the driver names and bugcheck error codes from your dumps and we may be able to help. The `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` bugcheck code typically points to bad memory, often RAM or hard drive. It may be worth running a `MemTest86+` live disk over the machine, and testing the hard drive for errors. This topic is a bit too broad though, there are infinite reasons you may be getting blue screens.

Comment: @PasinduPerera -  If you want help with your current BSOD, then provide the details here, not on a third-party website.

Comment: @Jonno - Except there is a way to display the information.....

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks - learn something new every day. Removed all the incorrect information from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help I just had to reinstall my windows  UEFI method. It seems my firmware have buggy legacy support, I think.  When I'm using UEFI method to boot Ubuntu new version there are no kernal panics. Everything runs smoothly.