# How to enable verbose BSOD screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

In Windows 10 the Blue Screen of Death:

[image]

hides the parameters of the kernel panic:

[image]

Ideally you would tell the user to write them down, or take a picture:

```
(0xC0000005, 0x8A9A8020, 0x8B39AEC4, 0x8B39ABC0)
```

And then i'd know:

- The exception code that was not handled: `0xc0000005` *(`STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`)*
- The address where the exception occurred: `0x8A9A8020`
- The address of the exception record: `0x8B39AEC4`
- The address of the context record: `0x8B39ABC0`

It's obviously more useful when its something like:

- Indicates the cause of the failure: `4` *(Unable to create GUID string from binary GUID.)*
- NTSTATUS code: `0xA00A0007` *(`E_OUTOFMEMORY`)*

But regardless of my motivations, i would like to disable the friendly BSOD in favor of the informative one.

### Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [Blue Screen Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/blue-screen-data)
- [I wrote the original blue screen of death, sort of](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140910-00/?p=44113)
- [Steve Ballmer did not write the text for the blue screen of death](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140909-00/?p=44123)

Comment: In this question https://superuser.com/questions/1035441/how-to-make-windows-10-bsod-show-more-details-like-older-versions-of-windows they say that you can create a simple registry key, which will show you information like the old BSOD did